# Can netcat be made to work in a passthrough way

Tags: linux, networking, apache-spark, network-programming, netcat

I'm using `netcat` as a bridge between some services and a spark streaming instance. For example, the service sends message to an `host:port` that net cat is listening to and then the idea is that spark can then consume this. However is there a way to make netcat passthrough, i.e. to act as a really simple server and literally listen and emit.

```
ncat -lk localhost 5005
```

This shows that I can get my messages send from my first service. But I get nothing from spark which listens to the same host:port. Is there a way to make this work?

One suggestion was to use the piping with `mkfifo backpipe` however the problem now is that when running my spark instance is listening on 5006 but it seems this connection doesn`t seem alive. My service sends to 5005 and then netcat should pipe it to 5006, but how can I make the service on 5006 to be always present such that my spark instance can listen to it?

```
mkfifo backpipe
nc -kl localhost 5005 0<backpipe | nc localhost 5006 1>backpipe
```

I also tried the following for good measure:

```
nc -klp 5005 -w 5 localhost 5006
```

But the issue is always that spark cannot consume with the following error:

```
Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Restarting receiver with delay 2000ms: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:5006 - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Comment: If available netpipes package with faucet and hose might be a better match, but with `mkfifo`  at hand it should work with `netcat` as eg described at [bidirectional socat functionality with nc](http://superuser.com/questions/363688/bidirectional-socat-functionality-with-nc?newreg=5312edc53c59492a9b4b9b9ba1a4f725)

Comment: @Dilettant I tried this and updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the version of netcat you use? And what operating system? If you use traditional netcat (not BSD-one used for Spark examples) you have to provide port argument:

```
nc -lk -p 5005
```